# Compare two hours inside while loop

Tags: php, datetime, while-loop

I'm trying to echo list of hours.

```
<?php 
    $startTime = "9:00:00";
    $endTime = "19:00:00";
    $st = strtotime($startTime);

    $et = strtotime($endTime);


    while ($st < $et) {
        echo $st = date( "H:i", strtotime('+30 minutes', $st) );
        echo '<br>';

    } 
?>
```

Inside that list, users will choose their reservation hour. But my while loop works like infinite loop.

Comment: You were almost there, your mistake was trying to combine two statements into one line.  The first line in your while loop should be two `$st=strtotime('+30 minutes',$st);` and `echo (date("H:i:,$st);` (your combined line accidentally does a type conversion from `int` to `string`).  There's no need to use `DateTime`.  However, be careful building dates like this - in the example it's fine, but if your hour range includes 2am, and it runs on daylight saving's transition day you'll get 0 or 2 02:00.  You could also model this as `for($i=9;$i<19;$i+=.5) {printf("%02d:%02d\n",$i,($i*60)%60);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like the previous answer, you're messing with data types while doing arithmetic.
PHP ships with built-in date time [arithmetic](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.examples-arithmetic.php) through [date and time API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).
Your code could look much more clear and elegant and less error prone (no strtotime(), conversion, etc)
You could do something like this instead:

```
<?php 

$startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '9:00:00');
$endTime = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '19:00:00');
$interval = new DateInterval('PT30M'); // 30 minutes

$reservation = [];

while ($startTime <= $endTime) {
    $reservation[] = $startTime->format('H:i');

    $startTime->add($interval);    
}

echo join(PHP_EOL, $reservation) . PHP_EOL;
```

Links:

- [Date/Time Arithmetic](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.examples-arithmetic.php)

Answer (score 1):

You're converting `$st` from a integer (timestamp) with `strtotime()` to a string with `date()` so your loop keeps going since `while (string < integer)...` is always true.

You can do this instead:

```
while ($st < $et) {
  $st += (30 * 60); // Add 30 minutes in seconds
  echo date("H:i", $st);
  echo '<br>';
}
```